# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).removeClass(...).affix is not a function at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Tags: jquery

Estou com o problema no jQuery,me diz que affix não é uma função,ja fiz tudo o que sei e mais e mesmo assim não pude resolver..podem me ajudar?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    if ( ($(window).height() + 100) < $(document).height() ) {
        $('#cta-buttons-wrapper').removeClass('hidden').affix({
            offset: {
                top: 100
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu código está correto, e se dá erro no `affix`, o `jquery` foi carregado corretamente, então o problema é no próprio `affix`.

Ele foi removido no `boostrap` a partir da versão 4: 
http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#components

> Dropped the Affix jQuery plugin. We recommend using a position: sticky
>   polyfill instead

Ou seja, removido e sugerido usar `position: sticky`